# Как сокращать слово «крымскотатарский»?

Tags: орфография, прилагательные, сокращения

Как сокращать слово «крымскотатарский»? Речь о языке.

Comment: Просто для сведения (и для удобства — тоже). Когда Вы начинаете набирать название метки, то в поле "всплывает" несколько подобных, в которых имеется походящий (смысловой) "набор букв". Не нужно было создавать новую метку "сокращение", потому что уже имелась метка "сокращения" (на сегодня — 54 вопроса).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Российская Академия наук, Институт русского языка им. В.В.Виноградова. А.Е.Аникин Русский этимологический словарь:
Принятые сокращения. Языки и диалекты

**кр.-тат. — крымскотатарский язык**

крым. — крымские говоры (рус.)

кубан. — кубанские говоры (рус.)

Источник: [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Обсуждение_шаблона:Lang-crh](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0:Lang-crh)

Comment: По ответу получается, что «крымскотатарский» пишется через дефис. Но оно пишется слитно, как в таком случае сокращать его? Спасибо!

Comment: В словаре Лопатина  "Слитно, раздельно или через дефис" (2012)  дано дефисное написание. В таком случае:  кр.-тат. — крымско-татарский язык. Другие варианты просто не просматриваются.

Comment: В Крыму пишут слитно.

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю ситуацию. В Сети встречаются две формы письма, но Грамота.ру и Словарь рекомендуют дефисное написание. При слитном написании сокращенная форма пишется через дефис: кр.-тат. (это обычная практика для таких названий).  А если полная форма пишется через дефис? Наверное, сокращенная форма будет писаться тоже через дефис (найти этот момент в правилах не удается). Получается, что при разном написании полной формы сокращенная форма будет иметь одинаковое письмо (кр.-тат.). Или не так? Как у вас пишутся обе формы?